# PrimeFaces Datatable

Tags: jsf, datatable, primefaces

I'm using the Primefaces datatable Complex in my file.xhtml and I want to retrieve the ID of the row that I selected to remove it or modify it. Is there any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go Naruto...

First you you need to populate the table with objects that got id

than add a "delete" column to the table

```
<p:column headerText="Delete">
       <p:commandLink ajax="true" action="#{hoursReportBean.removeEntity}" update="@form" process="@this" styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-trash">
           <f:setPropertyActionListener
                 target="#{hoursReportBean.selectedHourReportsToDeleteFromTable}"
                 value="#{hourReport}" />
       </p:commandLink>
</p:column> 

public String removeEntity(){
...
use the id of the object selectedHourReportsToDeleteFromTable.getId() in order to delete it from the list
...

}
```

Rasengan?